# finding type of a dll functions ? how to see them?

Tags: c#, dll, serial-port, device, cardreader

I am developing a .net program that needs to communicate with a magnetic card reader/writer.
it has a DLL but i couldnt find its functions and the producer company told me that i have to use only with serial port commands.
In its manual, there is some commands that has been explained not clear enough ! I tried to use them but i couldn't get any response for non of commands.
Does any body has experience with card reader devices ?!
Is there any  handshaking or initialization i need to set ?!

My card reader model is : Skankyo 6940

Comment: I think, asking the device vendor will be more productive solution.

Answer (score 2):

As said Dennis asking a vendor and reading its docmentation is more productice and most accurate way you can approach to work with the library .

Alternatively  you may think of using: [DUMPBIN.EXE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429/en-us) utility, to dump all export functions of that (presumably C) dll. I repeat,in this way is much harder then reading a documentation, but, yes, you can also find some "hidden gems".

Hope this helps.